# SQL Server - Why Alter Table Adding Nullable Columns to a Table causes a Rebuild

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, alter-table

We have a 250GB DB containing a 180GB Table (55M rows perhaps 550 cols) to which we are adding 24 new blank columns to the end via;

```
ALTER TABLE [Rpt].[tblHoldings]      
ADD 
    [Rating01AgencyCode] VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating01TypeCode]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating01Code]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating01Score]      FLOAT (53)   NULL,          
    [Rating02AgencyCode] VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating02TypeCode]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating02Code]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating02Score]      FLOAT (53)   NULL,          
    [Rating03AgencyCode] VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating03TypeCode]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating03Code]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating03Score]      FLOAT (53)   NULL,          
    [Rating04AgencyCode] VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating04TypeCode]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating04Code]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating04Score]      FLOAT (53)   NULL,          
    [Rating05AgencyCode] VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating05TypeCode]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating05Code]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating05Score]      FLOAT (53)   NULL,          
    [Rating06AgencyCode] VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating06TypeCode]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating06Code]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,          
    [Rating06Score]      FLOAT (53)   NULL ;
```

We have added 75 cols to this table using the same method in the past and it has only taken a few seconds.  This time round in an Elastic Azure Pool (800 EDTU) I set the DB max size to **500GB and it ran out of space** after running the above query for **6 hours**.

It would seem to be indirectly rebuilding the table in the background or more (even though this is a TSQL call that does not involve copying the table directly) - odder still is that even if it rebuilt the table why does it need MORE than another ~180 GB (i.e. 250GB + another 180GB should be less than 500GB)

Note: These are not indexed columns with any defaults or anything else not shown above

I am very interested in discovering whether this is expected behaviour.  Are there any conditions where adding nullable columns to the end of table triggers a rebuild and if so what conditions force this and why is it consuming more than the original table?

Comment: Just look at those column names makes me cringe - you should use **proper relational modelling** - and not something like this - this **violates** even the **first normal form** of relational database design !

Comment: @marc_s this is not meant to be a normalized table.  It is meant to be the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sum of the row width is greater than the page size (roughly 8KB), there may be some work required to try to allow your schema to fit into a page.  Fixed size fields, such as float, need to be on the page in all cases.  SQL does have functionality to take some variable-sized fields and put them off-row in some cases.  This could account for the sizeof(data) operation, perhaps, though it is really just speculation without a full repro.

The vocabulary for what may be happening is that the DDL operation would need to modify all rows to complete the operation.  It is not a "rebuild" as you would rebuild an index by building a new one and moving all data to it.  SQL does have logic to have, whenever possible, "online" schema operations meaning that if we can avoid doing sizeof(data) operations we do so.  That includes adding columns with no default value defined (so we don't have to touch all existing rows in the table to set the new default value for those existing rows).  There are some restrictions on this, however.  Please refer to the online documentation for the WITH(ONLINE=ON) syntax on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Having multiple environments using the same structure - we had inconsistent outcomes where some would happen near instantly while others force some kind of full table operation.

Comment: SQL has two layers of metadata - we call them "RE" (relational engine) and "SE" (storage engine).  The bottom layer can be a bit different than the upper in the case of add/drop operations.  This can potentially impact when you hit limits when adding columns that cause sizeof(data) operations.  the with online=on option should let you catch these by fast-failing the alter in the case when it requires sizeof(data) so you can schedule at off hours or consider alternative model to adjust